# How do you calculate your "alternative tax net operating loss"?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, losses, alternative-minimum-tax

In 2013 I had gains from trading futures (Section 1256 contracts) and then in 2014 I had losses trading futures.  A few months ago I amended my 2013 tax return to claim a refund via a futures loss carryback.

The IRS sent me a letter saying they need additional documentation.  Specifically it says:

> Your claim did not include enough information to support the new calculation of the alternative minimum tax that resulted from the carryback. Please submit a **calculation of your alternative tax net operating loss** and a completed Form 6251, Alternative Minimum Tax-Individuals, for the year of the loss. We will also need copies of the original Form 6251 and a revised Form 6251 for each carryback year.

It also mentions a few more forms that I need to send (1040, 6781, Schedule D).

I sent the letter to my CPA who prepared my tax returns and amended 2013 return, and he sent me the documentation.

One thing I am not sure about is the "calculation of your alternative tax net operating loss".  Is that separate from the Forms 6251 that the letter mentions?

My CPA included the "**Form 1045 - AMT NOL Carryover Worksheet - 2014**" with the documentation that he sent me.  (To be clear, I never filed Form 1045.)  The worksheet has numbers filled in for the "2nd preceding tax year ended 12/31/12" and "1st preceding tax year ended 12/31/13" columns.  Would this worksheet satisfy the request for a "calculation of your alternative tax net operating loss"?

Also, should any of the numbers from the AMT NOL Carryover Worksheet have been placed on the revised Form 6251 for 2013?  I noticed that Form 6251 for 2013 has a couple lines related to NOLs (Line 10: Net operating loss deduction, and Line 11: Alternative tax net operating loss deduction), but my CPA left both of those lines blank.